# regex case insensitivity

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

How would I make the following case insensitive?

```
if ($(this).attr("href").match(/\.exe$/))
{
// do something
}
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Put an `i` after the closing slash of the regex.

So your code would look like this:

```
if ($(this).attr("href").match(/\.exe$/i))
```

Answer (score 5):

With `/i` modifier:

```
if ($(this).attr("href").match(/\.exe$/i))
{
// do something
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Another option would be to simply manipulate the case to what you want.

It appears as though you are trying to match against lowercase characters.

So you could do this:

```
if ($(this).attr("href").toLowerCase().match(/\.exe$/)) {
     // do something
}
```

In fact, you could use `.indexOf()` instead of a regex if you wanted.

```
if ($(this).attr("href").toLowerCase().indexOf('.exe') > -1) {
     // do something
}
```

Of course, this would match `.exe` in the middle of the string as well, if that's an issue.

Finally, you don't really need to create a jQuery object for this. The `href` property is accessible directly from the element represented by `this`.

```
if ( this.href.toLowerCase().match(/\.exe$/) ) {
     // do something
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if ($(this).attr("href").match(/\.exe$/i))
{
// do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unlike the `match()` function, the `test()` function returns `true` or `false` and is generally preferred when simply testing if a *RegEx* matches.  The `/i` modifier for **case insensitive** matching works with both functions.

Example using `test()` with `/i`:

```
const link = $('a').first();

if (/\.exe$/i.test(link.attr('href')))
   $('output').text('The link is evil.');
```

[image: evil link]

Fiddle with the code:
https://jsfiddle.net/71tg4dkw

**Note:**
Be aware of evil links that hide their file extension, like:
`https://example.com/evil.exe?x=5`

Documentation for `test()`:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test